# Origen de la acepción "castigo" de la palabra "puro"

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

La palabra [**puro**](https://dle.rae.es/puro) tiene, como décima acepción:

> 10. m. coloq. Castigo o sanción. *Le han metido un puro por conducir sin carné.*

que no parece guardar ninguna relación con el resta de las acepciones.
Por lo que he podido averiguar, aparece por primera vez en la edición de 1985 del DLE:

> **meter un puro**: fr. vulg. *Mil.* Arrestar, imponer un castigo

¿Cómo adquirió "puro" esa acepción de "castigo"?

Comment: palabra pura no puro.

Comment: Ahora, ha cambiado la jugada. Ha puesto comillas a puro en la pregunta. Vale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se asocia a una raíz indoeuropea peu-1, peu̯ǝ- : pū̆-, en el argot militar hace alusión a introducir miembro masculino como castigo en un cuartel, personalmente lo asocio con el fuego.

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/16371526.pdf

https://books.google.cl/books?id=ISOkaIFXJmMC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425&dq=meter+un+puro+cuarteles&source=bl&ots=WmX99IhGRc&sig=ACfU3U0sdezu2pNA2X6Bju3dhmiA9BSUVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir2sWPws_zAhXGGbkGHalPAe8Q6AF6BAgHEAM

https://starlingdb.org/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpokorny&first=1&text_root=pu&method_root=substring&text_meaning=sift&method_meaning=substring&text_ger_mean=&method_ger_mean=substring&text_grammar=&method_grammar=substring&text_comments=&method_comments=substring&text_derivative=&method_derivative=substring&text_material=&method_material=substring&text_ref=&method_ref=substring&text_seealso=&method_seealso=substring&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=number

Comment: ¿Origen sexual? Me parece poco verosimil

Comment: @Ananias Así de explícito, las traducciones con español coloquial de la península de libros que leído están llenas de frases parecidas.

Answer (score 0):

En [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?puro) se recoge:

> Además, por la figura fálica que tiene el cigarro se dijo como metáfora "meterle un
> puro" a alguien, como propinarle un fortísimo castigo. Esto era antes lenguaje
> cuartelado, pero parece ser que salió de los cuarteles y se difundió de tal modo que
> ahora figura en el DRAE como "imponer a alguien una sanción o castigo".

Answer (score 0):

---

Que tal?. Exposición; Origen de la acepción "castigo" de la palabra "puro"

En esta expresión, "puro", existen varias teorías que pueden encontrarse en cualquier lugar de la red, desde una expresión que nace en los cuarteles, a alguien que hace puré a otro, sin embargo, la que más se ajusta a la realidad es la siguiente.

Explicación:

*Se puede amenazar con meter un paquete, con empapelar, meter un puro, empurar, caerle un puro, echarle un puro a alguien. Cualquiera de estas expresiones tiene un mismo significado y un mismo origen.*

*En 1908 la Tabacalera Española quiso conmemorar el primer centenario de la sublevación del pueblo español contra la ocupación napoleónica, por ello puso a la venta un paquete de seis puros.*

*Este paquete de cigarros puros iba envuelto en papel de color crema pegado con goma, con un puro pintado y una frase impresa: «Seis cigarros marca grande 1,20 pesetas».
Comoquiera que hasta entonces los cigarros puros se vendían sueltos y sin envoltura —de manera que el fumador podía comprobar la calidad antes de su compra— y con la nueva forma de venta no era posible ver el producto antes de comprarlo, la gente empezó a decir, suspicaz, que el propósito de Tabacalera era deshacerse de un producto malo sin que el fumador pudiera percatarse hasta haberlo consumido.
Y que el único motivo del paquete era ocultar la baja calidad, de manera que así daban gato por liebre.*

*A los consumidores no les quedó más remedio que tragar el paquete aceptando su compra, ya fuera de buena o mala calidad.
Por ello, expresiones como meterle un paquete a uno, meter un puro, empapelar a alguien o empurar, significan tanto como jugar una mala pasada, como propinar un castigo que el otro debe aguantar*

Espero te haya servido. Saludos.
Diego M.